# What is the first Deterministic BIP39 Wallet released?

Tags: wallet, mnemonic-seed

I'm studying the BIP39 and the seed phrase.
I can read this doc (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0039) and I can find `Created: 2013-09-10`.
In bitcoin talk I can read this article (https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=19137) with date `June 18, 2011`

I can find this post about Electrum release, https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=100502.0 but i'ts just a seed not a seedphrase (or I mistake about it?)

So When did the first Wallet (and which one) implement the BIP39?
Or when the user started to use it to store his keys?

Comment: The bitcointalk post you link to was the original idea for deterministic wallets. It was adopted in the Armory wallet, and later a (different) scheme was standardized as BIP32 (disclaimer: I'm the author). BIP39 came even later and proposed replacing BIP32's seed key with a seed phrase. I don't know which wallets first implemented BIP32 or BIP39, but I wanted to make it clear that currently adopted standards had several independent components, developed by different people, spread over several years.

Comment: thanks @PieterWuille. So we could say that the Seed phrase came from 2013-09-10, and we could say that after that date a wallet could implement it. I mean the 2013-sept-10 is the release of that. 

My questoin is, what is the first software wallet adopted the BIP39? in which date?

Comment: Yes, I understand the question - I don't know the answer to that. I just wanted to give some background here.

Comment: thanks for your answer Pieter very kind